# how to scan and connect to itag-bluetooth tracer in Android

Tags: android

I need to develop an app that scans and detect itag-wireless-bluetooth-4-0-anti-lost-alarm-safety-security-smart-tracker. Is it possible to do? Does it require separate SDK? Or is it possible to scan and connect using the code for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices?

I tried using https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
with this I could scan and connect devices in the range. But I couldn't read value from the devices. e.g. I connected to a MI Band 2. It listed the services it broadcast, in which it has Heart Rate Measurements. But when I tried to read its value it threw an exception with message:

> "characteristic.getvalue() returned null

Comment: Where's the manufacturer's website? Where are the technical specs? Should the Stack Overflow community try to guess which device you are using and google for the information? Possibly it's just a regular Bluetooth LE device "advertising" itself and in that case you can detect it without any SDKs just by using standard Android APIs. The [documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2462/bluetooth-and-bluetooth-le-api/21314/find-nearby-bluetooth-low-energy-devices) has some example code.

Comment: https://www.flipkart.com/pinglo-itag-wireless-bluetooth-4-0-anti-lost-alarm-safety-security-smart-tracker/p/itmeqb74xzc4fgc6?pid=SYMEQB74AYFA5RGD&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTSYMEQB74AYFA5RGDPEPCRD&qH=19558544f95b7dc1
  
This is the device my organization is planning to buy.For this i couldn't any further details..Please help me with this

Comment: One option would be to just buy one and try it out. There are also some Bluetooth LE scanner apps in Play Store, so it's possible to try out without any coding. If they detect the device, then you should be able to detect it with your own app too. It seems to have a button. It might just show up as regular input device (like a keyboard) in Android, but I'm not familiar with the product.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion:)

Comment: And I didn't want to sound too blunt, so hopefully it wasn't taken as such. :)